# How to publish a folder to Azure App Service?

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a .Net Core project. As part of my database Context class I have some seed data to insert into the database. This seed data is deserialized from a seed.json file in the root directory and holds paths to images in it. These images are in a folder in the project. Before inserting the data I get these images, upload them to Azure cloud storage, and change the paths to point to there. This works great locally.

So now I publish my app to Azure App Service and a FileNotFound exception appears.
It can no longer find the images in the project. Looking at the filesystem on Azure's Kudu dashboard I don't see my project folders but instead a bunch of .dll and .pdb files. I can only speculate that Azure maybe bundles the folders into .dll's?

I can still access the wwwroot/images just fine but would prefer not to for securitys sake.

What can I do to publish my folder to their filesystem or get access to my files on their filesystem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to set your project working directory in Program.cs. You can then access *your files* relative to the .dll directory.

```
var currentDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
config.SetBasePath(currentDir)
```

And possibly need to copy across the seed.json and images folder to the output of the project:

```
`<Content Include="seed.json">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
<Content Include="images/**/*">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

`

Hope it helps
Dave

Comment: Hey Dave, thanks for that. It was the copy to output directory setting I was missing.